# In React, when inheriting propTypes, how do I avoid duplication?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using an abstract superclass for some React components that share methods and some (but not all) props.

```
class AbstractStory extends Component { ... }
AbstractStory.propTypes = {
  storyForm: PropTypes.string,
  timestamp: PropTypes.number
}

class NewContentStory extends AbstractStory { ... }
```

I'm assuming that if the propTypes of the subclass don't differ from the superclass, I can leave them undeclared on the subclass, and they will be inherited from the superclass.

But, if there are additional properties of the subclass, is there a good way to declare them without restating what is declared on the superclass? Is there any issues doing it like this?

```
NewContentStory.propType = {... AbstractStory, newProp: PropTypes.string}
```

What about if the subclass modifies a property declared on the superclass (making it required, adding shape to an object, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

The real answer is that by convention you don't really want to extend components other than `React.Component` as functional composition is the primary way of abstraction in React.

In other words: You should nest components, rather than extending classes in React.

Comment: How does this answer the question though? How do you avoid duplication of the `propTypes` object properties?

Comment: Sometimes the answer is not what you may expect. That doesn't make the answer wrong.