# Is inheritance in React components an anti-pattern?

Tags: reactjs

I asked another question that involved inheritance among React components.  One [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55300998/213042) stated that inheritance is counter-indicated for React components.  I can construct examples where inheritance could add clarity and reduce code.  Is inheritance an anti-pattern for React components?  Why or why not?

Comment: What do you mean by inheritance? As in creating a class-based component and then have another component extend that?

Comment: Yes - Javascript (ES6) native class inheritance with `extends`

Comment: At Facebook, we use React in thousands of components, and we haven’t found any use cases where we would recommend creating component inheritance hierarchies.
from: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: inheritance in any language is considered an anti-pattern, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: And I agree, been using it for about 3 years now and can't think of any good use case... If you do what you are suggesting, you'll eventually end up with much more to maintain...

Comment: @SakoBu That link is very helpful.  Thank you.  Care to make it an official answer?

Comment: You will find [this post](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/how-to-use-classes-and-sleep-at-night-9af8de78ccb4) by Dan Abramov, one of the co-creators of React very enlightening

Comment: Sure. Will probably be helpful for others...

Comment: It's worth noting that in the piece that @ManavM cites, Dan Abramov gives tepid support to one level of inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common question from developers coming from an OOP background... Here is a link from the official docs that clearly explains why composition is preferred over inheritance:

https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html